# How to generate report gridview to Pdf

Tags: asp.net, report

how to create report gridview to pdf.plz tell me what is the steps to be followed

Comment: Use Html to PDF tool - http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create HTML from the GridView data
Use iTextSharp to convert from HTML to PDF

Hope these links will be helpful

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ITextSharpHelperClass.aspx

http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/